# JavaScript Namespace Pattern

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, module, namespaces

I came across this JavaScript intricacy and was struggling to find the difference. Its about JavaScript namespaces. My question is simple, one form of namespace definition looks like this:

1. var nameSpace = (***f***)();

the other one looks like this

1. var nameSpace = (***f*** ());

here ***f*** refers to the full function definition like function(vars) { ....}. I know that ***1*** executes the body before returning the handle to the return object. But how does **2** differ from ***1***?

Comment: (by the way, these are called IIFEs)

Comment: http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

Answer (score 1):

They both accomplish the exact same thing, but Crockford recommends the second one.

I'm not sure what you mean by "namespace" though. They both create a new closure, which you can use for local variables, so I guess it's kind of like a namespace.

Comment: http://jsperf.com/anonymous-func-declaration (this is very weird, I remember I just [had this conversation a day ago](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/11657226#11657226))

Comment: @Joseph So does both 1 & 2 cause the execution of the function body before handle to the return object is returned?

Comment: @Choksi - Yes. You can do whatever you want before returning from that anonymous function.

Comment: @Joesph Thanks. I appreciate your response.

Comment: @Josesh Its' probably not a namespace. I may have got the terminology wrong there.