# How to dynamically disable and remove everything about a js file?

Tags: javascript, dom, dynamic

I have a page with small "applications" in it, and I want to switch between them without reloading the page.

Is there way to remove all the js code and variables and functions and intervals etc. etc. from the page, for one application which presents itself as a .js file?

Or would it be easier to just refresh the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have each application in its own namespace, (see for example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg578608.aspx or here: [JavaScript Namespace Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18690508/javascript-namespace-pattern) ) you could pass those namespaces into your particular part of the page, which would probably achieve something like this.

However depending on what kind of performance you want putting the applications in an iframe and dynamically loading different pages there might be better.

Comment: Iframe sounds like the easiest solution. I assume global variables will be removed too when I change the iframe? And yes I know I shouldn't use globals, but I do.

Comment: To scripts running within the iFrame, yes they will be removed, however the page surrounding it will still have the same global JavaScript state. (If necessary it is also possible to access that JavaScript within the iFrame by getting the parent of it's window object)